# How to format / test before every push in a Node.js monorepo?

Tags: node.js, package.json, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am aware of several tools like husky, lint-staged and prettier, currently I have a monorepo that is using yarn workspaces and lerna, before every push using git I want prettier to format my code and run a test script, it does not matter if this happens in every project but it would be nice to only run those scripts in the projects that are changed ofcourse, my question is what tools can really help me with this and how do I set them up? Do I set them up for each project individually or can I setup something in my root package.json? It currently looks like

```
{
  "name": "orgname",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "lerna run build",
    "dev": "lerna run start --stream --parallel",
    "test": "lerna run test --"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm test"
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.22.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at git hooks. It let’s you run scripts before/after an operation like push.

Comment: Husky allows me to setup those hooks but I am still a bit unsure if I should be setting them up in the root of my monorepo or in individual projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `lint: ...` script inside package.json of every lerna packages, for example;

**./packages/web/package.json**

```
 ...
  "scripts": {
   "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --fix"
  },
```

**./packages/api/package.json**

```
 ...
  "scripts": {
   "lint": "eslint --fix src",
  }
```

and in the main package.json you can add a lint script that runs every lint command of packages.

Lastly add it to the husky pre-commit hook, so it will run every time before you commit.

**./package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
   "lint": "lerna run lint"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn lint && yarn test"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, why do people setup a single script inside a lint-staged entry? Why don't they directly add that script inside the husky hook by chaining like you did?

Comment: With lint-staged you can write matching patterns and apply different linting commands to every matching pattern that is why it is used I believe, but I don't need it since I can only do my linting operation with one eslint command in both projects

Comment: There's another HUGE advantage in using lintstaged: linting partially applied commits, where not all changed files are going to be commited so the linting command can be executed into those specific changes. In a monorepo, as it grows rapidly, it will be a great pattern to help with this kind of scenarios.

Comment: @LuísBrito now I understand what does `git add` do in `lint staged`, it basically checks which files are modified in git add and lints only those right?

Comment: Yes, it's a little more complicated than that in the real life, it actually stash stuff and rewrite files on the go while being executed using git hashs, but the result is that you can lint partial changes to the package of even of partial changes to a single file, if not all its changes were yet staged into git.

Comment: The name comes from "linting" only what is "staged" in git for a new commit. Just as an example, I'm working with a production application that's developed as a monorepo, currently with more than 50 different packages. Running a full lint, or a lint only where I've changed some files, is a game changer for daily productivity.

Comment: You should also see the `--since HEAD` lerna args to apply the command only in packages that changed since last commit.

Answer (score 1):

Added a comment to the selected answer about using the `lint-staged` package, basically it enables you to apply linting and other routines specifically to changed files, and not all the package. It may be useful, depending on how you're using the monorepo approach.

/packages/example-name/.lintstagedrc.json

```
{
  "*.{js,ts}": ["eslint --fix", "git add"]
}
```

/packages/example-name/package.json

```
{
  [...]

  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  }

  [...]
}
```

/package.json

```
{
  [...]

  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lerna run precommit --since HEAD"
    }
  },

  [...]
}
```

For more information: https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged